# Jenkins pipeline not able to read method in groovy file

Tags: jenkins, groovy

My jenkins pipeline not able to read method in groovy file.

Please find below details

The error

```
Checking out Revision b3a3877b909060d87b5ee3c99921a93524804890 (refs/remotes/new-repo/jenkins)
 > C:\Users\muhammadnur.afiq\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\bin\git.exe config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > C:\Users\muhammadnur.afiq\AppData\Local\Programs\Git\bin\git.exe checkout -f b3a3877b909060d87b5ee3c99921a93524804890 # timeout=10
Commit message: "update"
Posting build status of INPROGRESS to mad-instance for commit id [fbf8c39939a1654cc2f707a1c23208488e742628] and ref 'null'
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Function Call)
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] echo
================= INSIDE JENKINS ====================
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.lang.Class.printecho() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
Possible solutions: println(), println(java.io.PrintWriter), print(java.lang.Object), print(java.io.PrintWriter), println(java.lang.Object), printf(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.groovy.SandboxInterceptor.onMethodCall(SandboxInterceptor.java:154)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker$1.call(Checker.java:161)
    at org.kohsuke.groovy.sandbox.impl.Checker.checkedCall(Checker.java:165)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.SandboxInvoker.methodCall(SandboxInvoker.java:17)
    at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:13)
    at ___cps.transform___(Native Method)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationGroup.methodCall(ContinuationGroup.java:86)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.dispatchOrArg(FunctionCallBlock.java:113)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.FunctionCallBlock$ContinuationImpl.fixName(FunctionCallBlock.java:78)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor113.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ContinuationPtr$ContinuationImpl.receive(ContinuationPtr.java:72)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.ConstantBlock.eval(ConstantBlock.java:21)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Next.step(Next.java:83)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:174)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable$1.call(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport$ThreadCategoryInfo.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:129)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.GroovyCategorySupport.use(GroovyCategorySupport.java:268)
    at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.Continuable.run0(Continuable.java:163)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.access$001(SandboxContinuable.java:18)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.SandboxContinuable.run0(SandboxContinuable.java:51)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThread.runNextChunk(CpsThread.java:185)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.run(CpsThreadGroup.java:400)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup.access$400(CpsThreadGroup.java:96)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:312)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsThreadGroup$2.call(CpsThreadGroup.java:276)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsVmExecutorService$2.call(CpsVmExecutorService.java:67)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at hudson.remoting.SingleLaneExecutorService$1.run(SingleLaneExecutorService.java:139)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$1.run(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:28)
    at jenkins.security.ImpersonatingExecutorService$1.run(ImpersonatingExecutorService.java:68)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Posting build status of FAILED to mad-instance for commit id [b3a3877b909060d87b5ee3c99921a93524804890] and ref 'null'
Finished: FAILURE
```

JenkinsFile

```
library("my-shared-library") _

import my.com.mad.Context

pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Function Call') {
            steps {
                script {        
                    echo "================= INSIDE JENKINS ===================="
                    Context.printecho()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Groovy

```
import groovy.transform.Field

def printecho(){
    echo "================= INSIDE GROOVY ====================="
}
return this
```

Thank you.....................................................................................................................................................................................

Comment: At first, please post your code in the question and not an image of your code. Regarding your issue, you are calling the printecho function with `{} `which is an empty groovy closure that is passed to the function, but your function doesn't receive any parameters and therefore you get the error, just use `printecho()`  without the curly parenthesis.

Comment: @NoamHelmer hi. i removed {} and retest hit same error.

Comment: is your groovy file inside the `vars` folder? if so what is the name of the file? if not where does it reside?